# Error message when trying to install nginx on Ubuntu 12.04.3 x32

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, vps

I am trying to install a LEMP-stack on a VPS running Ubuntu 12.0.4.3 x32 following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-12-04). I am getting the following error-message when I try to restart nginx:

```
Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart" in       
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:21 
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

This lets me logically assume that something is wrong with my nginx.conf, which looks like this:

```
  GNU nano 2.2.6                                             File: /etc/nginx/sites-available/default                                                                                      Modified


    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name 192.XXX.XXX.X;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

I am also not able to open the info.php in my browser, which I created.

Could you please advice me what went wrong?

Comment: Another part of the error says **in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default** line 21. You should check there as well.

Comment: could you please also share `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` because this file seems fine

Comment: Just found the error; the first line was uncommented, so that the file got rejected. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an proper guide on [installing LEMP Stack on Ubuntu](http://www.thegeekbyte.com/linux/2547/how-to-install-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu/) if this does't help you type sudo nginx -t and this will tell you where you are having mistake in your config file.